# How do i open a text file with openFileDialog when the content of the file is also with hebrew letters?

Tags: c#, winforms

This is the code to open the file:

```
private void openToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
            openFileDialog1.Title = "Please Select A Text File Or A Word File To Open";
            openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "c:\\";
            openFileDialog1.FileName = null;
            openFileDialog1.Filter = "Text Or Word|*.txt;*.doc;*.docx";
            openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 1;
            openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;
            DialogResult result1 = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
            string file1 = openFileDialog1.FileName;
            if (result1 == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                string s = File.ReadAllText(file1);
                textBox1.Text = s;
            }
        }
```

This is the source content of the text file:

```
שיעור ראשון : יצירת פרוייקט חדש:
-----------------------------

New> Android > Android Application Project

Application Name > שם האפליקציה כפי שהמשתמשים יראו אותה.

Project Name > שם הפרוייקט כפי שיופיע ב Eclipse ושם הספרייה.
```

And this is what im getting in the textBox:

```
����� ����� : ����� ������� ���:
-----------------------------

New> Android > Android Application Project

Application Name > �� ��������� ��� ��������� ���� ����.

Project Name > �� �������� ��� ������ � Eclipse ��� �������.

Package Name > ���� ����� �� ����� ���� ����� ������� ����� ������ : ExtractLightning ��� ����.

Minimum Required SDK > ������ ������ ����� �� �������� ���������� ��� ����� ������ �� � API LEVEL.

Target SDK > ������ ������ ����� �� ������ ������� ������ �� ��������� ���. ���� ����� �� ��������� ��� �� ������ ������
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the encoding to the [Windows-1255](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1255) code page (or another code page if you know it).

```
Encoding enc = Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1255");
string s = File.ReadAllText(file1, enc);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the overload of `File.ReadAllText` that supports [specifying an encoding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143369.aspx).

Joel's article ["The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)"](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) is required reading on character sets and encoding.

If the encoding is unknown then checkout [chardetsharp](https://code.google.com/p/chardetsharp/) which can help detect the character encoding of an unknown text.

Answer (score 1):

In

```
string s = File.ReadAllText(file1); //Without charset
Encoding hebrewEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1255");
string s = File.ReadAllText(file1, hebrewEncoding); //With charset
```

If you include a second parameter with the charset that includes hebrew characters the problem should go away.